# Help with the conditional probability in this problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The beacon of light from a prison turns on itself so it takes to light the same area 40 seconds. A prisoner organizing a prison break needing 27 seconds to reach and climb the wall. If the prisoner start a leak when choosing start hour randomly, ¿what is the probability that manages to escape without being seen?

Answer (score 2):

$13$ out of the $40$ seconds of one period are fine, so ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @iostream007 "This does not provide an answer to the question"... Really? Giving a hint seems quite appropriate to me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vaguely worded question. I am assuming that

(i) All points on the path the prisoner takes get lighted every 40s.

(ii) S(he) starts so that full use of the 40s is enabled.

With the above assumptions, P(not seen) = 1 if time for leak < 13s, and 0 if it is ≥ 13s.

Comment: Sorry, that was a translation error. Corrected the statement.

Comment: I understand "choosing start hour randomly", but "start a leak when choosing start hour randomly" boggles my imagination ! If the question isn't frivolous, I think that some translation error(s) still remain !